# Solr search result issue

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4, solrnet

I am using solr query to get names from product list. getting results but issue in loading results

Query

https://domainname:8983/solr/places/select/?json.wrf=getIt&rows=10&wt=json&q=product_name:(Sony*)

Results

Bravia Sony
Sonytv
Sony Led
Sony LCD

I want result like below

Sonytv
Sony Led
Sony LCD

I need to skip Bravia Sony result I want results that start with Sony

Comment: try boosting the same word or create another field for the product_name and apply non-tokeniser field type to it.

Answer (score 0):

create a copy field for product_name either use keyword tokeniser or you can add field type String as well. Hope it will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the query as '^Sony' , this will pick the matches starting with Sony